# Removing datapoints from list by using differential difference or something else

Tags: python

I am new to python coding and are trying to learn the best way possible

The problem I have run into regards removing/deleting some data points from a large data set using a list from a logical statement.

as an example if I have the list [1.576, 1.675, 1.4772, 1.4872, 10.1283, 1.2134, 1.234, ..., 32.12] how do I remove the higher number in my data set? Is it best to do by differential or setting a threshold which all values above should be deleted and how do I manage to do this?

Comment: Did you mean only removing the highest value from a list?

Comment: No for example removing all values above 10

Comment: i would suggest making a new list via list comprehension e.g. `[i for i in original_list if i < 10]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can remove the highest (I assume highest value in list, CMIIW) value of integer element in a list using list.remove() methode combine with max() function.

```
lst = [1.576, 1.675, 1.4772, 1.4872, 10.1283, 1.2134, 1.234, 32.12]
lst.remove(max(lst))

# [1.576, 1.675, 1.4772, 1.4872, 10.1283, 1.2134, 1.234]
```

**EDIT (Removing values above 10)**:

```
lst = [1.576, 1.675, 1.4772, 1.4872, 10.1283, 1.2134, 1.234, 32.12]
for i in lst:
    if i > 10:
        lst.remove(i)

# [1.576, 1.675, 1.4772, 1.4872, 1.2134, 1.234]
```

Or using list comprehension as suggested by @equatorial_daydreamer

```
lst = [1.576, 1.675, 1.4772, 1.4872, 10.1283, 1.2134, 1.234, 32.12]
lst[:] = [i for i in lst if i < 10]

# [1.576, 1.675, 1.4772, 1.4872, 1.2134, 1.234]
```

Note that `lst[:]` is still the same object ID as original `lst` which increase efficiency (only updating the content of `lst` instead of creating new list with the same name)

Comment: Don’t mention it. You can accept the answer as if it satisfied you, or you can change 'accepted answer' of other answer later if it might better solution for your problem. https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers